# How efficient is the CRC algorithm?

Tags: signals, signal-processing, crc

In my implementation of the CRC algorithm in 200,000 messages of k = 20 bits using 53 (110101) as the divisor with a bit error rate of 10^(-3) there are 4987 messages with error and only one of them goes through undetected. Are these valid results? Can the CRC algorithm be so efficient or do i probably have something wrong in my implementation?
(I am not posting my code because i just want some feedback on the results i want to do the debugging on my own)

-Edit: The CRC algorithm i used is the one [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modulo-2-binary-division/). I use the number 53 to divide the binary message and the remainder i get is the frame check sequence. This sequence is then appended to the end of the message and then the message gets transmitted. On the receiving end the transmitted message is again divided by 53 but this time the remainder should be 0 unless a bit error occurred. (Unnoticed bit errors can happen though)

Comment: You're using a 5-bit CRC? How many bits in the CRC? Each message is 20 bits? ("k" doesn't mean anything by itself.)

Comment: Again, is each message 20 bits? Are you appending a 5-bit CRC to each message?

Comment: It's 25 bits sorry for being late

Comment: "It" is what? The message is 25 bits? The message plus CRC is 25 bits? Ok, one more time. Is each message 20 bits? Are you then appending a 5-bit CRC to each message?

Answer (score 1):

It looks extremely likely that your implementation of the bit errors is incorrect.

If I am reading the question correctly and each message has 20 bits, then the expected number of messages in error is 200000 (1 - (1 - 10<sup>-3</sup>)<sup>20</sup>), which is 3962. The standard deviation is about the square root of that, about 63. Your 4987 messages is more than *16* standard deviations above the expected number! The probability of that happening by accident is less than 10<sup>-58</sup>. So you have a bug.

As for the false positives, you should expect about one (0.982 to be more precise), on average, for 200,000 20-bit messages with that bit error rate and that particular 5-bit CRC.

Far better for your specified conditions is the polynomial x<sup>5</sup> + x + 1 (`100011`). That gives 0.0071 false positives for that same case.

Comment: I calculated the same result, 3962. I didn't test it, but it seems unlikely for a 5 bit CRC to have a 2 bit failure case for a 20 bit message. CRC Zoo doesn't include hex 35 as one of the 6 bit polynomials for a 5 bit CRC. If I remember correctly, the probability of a 3 bit error in a 20 bit message would be (.001^3) (.999^17) (comb(20,3)) ~= 0.00000112.

Comment: You are right i added some clarification in my post about the algorithm used.

Comment: What is the minimum number of error bits to result in a false positive? Maybe this could be included in your answer  for the .0982 probability of a false positive in 200,000 test messages. Still waiting for the OP to clarify if message size including CRC is 20 bits or 25 bits.

Comment: It's 25 bits sorry for being late